# Domain routing to directory, .htaccess or DNS-magic?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, dns, tld

I have three domains of the same name with tlds: .com, .de and .ru.
Can I route the visitor depended on tld he had choosen?

As example: test.com routes to /english/ directory,
test.de to /german/ directory,
test.ru to /russian/ one.

I have full access to the server.

Comment: What web server are you using?

Comment: virtual server, apache based, ssh-access

Comment: You might consider redirecting based on user locale instead of the server name.

Answer (score 3):

You should make each site have its own document root. So instead of redirecting to /english, .com would just point to /home/www/mysite/english. If you are using Apache you can do this with [virtual hosts](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

Comment: ok, then I have three FTP-Logins. Thats the point. I need one main directory, where I have subdirectories for /english/, /german/ stuff. I cannot give my customer root-login.

Comment: huh? that has nothing to do with the document root. Are you on a shared hosting enviroment? can you edit hte apache.conf? If not you can have your cpanel point each domain to a different subdirectory.

Comment: that is virtual-server. I have found "http.include"-file. can i do something like this:

<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
 ServerName   test.com:80
 ServerAlias  www.test.com
 UseCanonicalName Off
 DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/english/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 1.1.1.1:80>
 ServerName   test.de:80
 ServerAlias  www.test.de
 UseCanonicalName Off
 DocumentRoot /var/www/vhosts/test.com/httpdocs/german/
</VirtualHost>
?

I can edit the file. The problem is, my server is running with plesk.

Comment: That is the Apache conf you need. I am not very familiar with plex. But there might be an option on the cpanel to manage domains or virtual hosts or subdomains. That is Where you want to do it. .conf files in an environment like that will likley be overwritten by the server software.